# Java/XML: Read XML to vector in java

Tags: java, xml

I have XML file with a lot of records in XML.
for example,

```
<ChinRecord>
      <p>(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(......)</p>
      <CP>
        <p>(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(......)</p>
      </CP>
      <origin>30Ntr431_C.TXT</origin>
      <What>t</What>
      <TZ>q84393</TZ>
      <wQ>WQ</wQ>
      <time>2009-11-4</time>
</ChinRecord>
<ChinRecord>
      <p>(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(......)</p>
      <CP>
        <p>(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(......)</p>
      </CP>
      <origin>30Ntr431_C.TXT</origin>
      <What>true</What>
      <TZ>7027AEC</TZ>
      <wQ>WQ</wQ>
      <time>2009-11-30</time>
</ChinRecord>
```

I use the next line:

```
Chin newRecord = (Chin)xstream.fromXML(xml);
```

(I have datatype of Chin)

and It's really give me the first record of the xml in `newRecord` . But What I do when I want to save all the records? I create new Vector, but how I acsses all the records in the file?
Thanks.

Comment: What is a "record" in your XML? Your example is not a valid XML document since it lacks a root.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Sorry, I edit it.

Comment: XStream is probably confused because of that.  It's stopping the parse after `</ChinRecord>` because it expects it to be the root element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the  `ObjectInputStream` of XStream as described here: http://x-stream.github.io/objectstream.html

But this would require to wrap your `ChinRecord`elements into some XML root:

```
<object-stream>
  <ChinRecord>
    ..
  </ChinRecord>
  <ChinRecord>
    ..
  </ChinRecord>
  ..
</object-stream>
```